# float text over an image, right-aligned

Tags: css, image, text, css-position

I have several nested divs and I'm trying to float some text over the bottom right corner of an image, then have more text to the right of the image. The floated text is showing up to the right of the entire line instead of the right of the image. The whole thing (along with other text) is wrapped in one big div, and if I add bottom:0px, the text I want to float shows up at the bottom of that.

It should be (with a number at the bottom right corner of the image)

[_1] caption

but I'm getting

[_] caption 1

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class='outerwrapper'>
      <div class='innerwrapper'>
        <img src='image.jpg'>
        <div class='floatedtext'>1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='caption'>image caption to the right<br></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outerwrapper
{
  clear: both;
  min-height: 45px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.innerwrapper
{
   clear:both;
}
.caption
{
   font-size:13px;
}
.floatedtext
{
   font-size:12px;
   position: absolute;
   right:0px;
   text-align:right;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerwrapper class needs to have position relative

http://jsfiddle.net/8SDvu/

that's the basics of it, you might want to add some paddings and margins where needed but I am sure you can figure those out

```
.innerwrapper
{
   clear:both;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}
```

might want to add

```
.floatedtext {
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did allot of changes to your css and to the way you laid out your HTML I believe this is what you are looking for. Please let me know if this works for you.
JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/4MXvj/

CSS

```
.outerwrapper
  {
  clear: both;
 min-height: 45px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  }
.innerwrapper
  {
  clear:both;
  }
  .innerwrapper img {
    width: 35%;
    height: 35%;
    display: block;
   }
  .innerwrapper div {
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

}
   .caption
     {
     font-size:13px;
     }
    .floatedtext
     {
     font-size:12px;

```
 }
```

HTML

```
<div>
   <div class='outerwrapper'>
   <div class='innerwrapper'>
    <img src='https://www.blackbaud.com/image/products/luminate-online/img_Advocacy.png'>
          <div class='floatedtext'>1</div>
          <div class='caption'>image caption to the right<br></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```